# How would I right a select statement to query this database?

Tags: mysql

How would I right a select statement if I wanted to find out how many people with the first name "Jim" have passed their test?

Also what about if I wanted to get the instructor Forename and Surname, the Client Forename and Surname and Date for every Test after 9:00 on 10/03/2015?

Here is the relational Schema for the database.

**Client** (**clientNo**, forename, surname, gender, address, telNo, proLicenceNo)

**Instructor** (**instructorID**, forename, surname, gender, address, telNo, licenceNo, *carNo*)

**Car** (**carNo**, regNo, model)

**Lesson** (***clientNo***, **onDate**, **atTime**, *instructorID*)

**Test** (***clientNo***, **onDate**, **atTime**, *instructorID*, *centreID*, status, reason)

**Centre** (**centreID**, name, address)

Primary keys are in bold and foreign keys are in italic. No foreign keys are allowed to be null.

Thanks! :)

Comment: What queries have you tried?

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem you're having when writing this SELECT statement? I'm not seeing how this will be useful to any future reader.

Comment: Sorry I was just really stuck with a few questions, I didn't really know where to start. I still can't do that second question so I was just looking for some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try joining between client and test table like:

```
SELECT c.forename, COUNT(c.forname)
FROM Client c INNER JOIN Test t
ON c.clientNo = t.clientNo
WHERE c.forename = 'Jim'
AND   t.status = 'PASS'
GROUP BY c.forname
```

Comment: That was perfect thanks! What about if I wanted to get the instructor (drop off and pick up) Forename and Surname, the Client Forename and Surname and Date for every Test after 9:00 on 10/03/2015

Comment: Thanks for the help by the way, I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what field/value constitutes passing makes it difficult to write such a query.
If i had to guess though Lets assume Test.Status = 'Passed'

```
select c.clientNo, c.forename, c.surname, c.gender, c.address, c.telNo, c.proLicenceNo 
    from Client c
    inner join Test t on t.clientNo = c.clientNo
where c.forename = 'Jim' and t.Status = 'Passed';
```

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-select-statement-query-data.aspx

Answer (score -1):

```
create table passed as
select a.clientno, a.forename, b.status from
client a inner join test b on a.clientno = b.clientno
where a.forename='Jim' and b.status='Pass';
```