# Writing a update statement to alter this database?

Tags: mysql

I am very stuck about how to write an update statement for this database. The instructor for the test at 29/04/2015 10:00 has changed to be the instructor with a Mini One. What would the SQL command be to make this change?

Here is the relational Schema for the database.

**Client** (**clientNo**, forename, surname, gender, address, telNo, proLicenceNo)

**Instructor** (**instructorID**, forename, surname, gender, address, telNo, licenceNo, *carNo*)

**Car** (**carNo**, regNo, model)

**Lesson** (***clientNo***, **onDate**, **atTime**, *instructorID*)

**Test** (***clientNo***, **onDate**, **atTime**, *instructorID*, *centreID*, status, reason)

**Centre** (**centreID**, name, address)

Primary keys are in bold and foreign keys are in italic. No foreign keys are allowed to be null.

Thanks for any help I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: SO is not a place where you post your homework and expect others to solve it. Show what you have tried and maybe somebody will help you figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would I right a select statement to query this database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395462/how-would-i-right-a-select-statement-to-query-this-database)

Comment: Where are you stuck?  What do you not understand?

Comment: I realise you start with UPDATE instructor but I think you have to reference multiple tables to make that single change which I'm finding confusing

Comment: Post the queries you've tried so far, show that you've actually put work into finding a solution. You may find the [Mysql Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) on UPDATE syntax helpful. Particularly multi-table updates, near the bottom.

Comment: I am so confused sorry, I got this, UPDATE instructor
SET i.carNo=c.carNo
WHERE i.carNo=

Comment: The `UPDATE` statement can support `JOIN`s, just like `SELECT` can.  `UPDATE instructor i JOIN Test t ON t.instructorID=i.instructorID SET i.carNo='' WHERE ...`

Comment: Ah okay thanks, looking at question again however it looks like I may have misunderstood the wording slightly, it looks like I should be instead altering the test table instead of the instructor table... hmmm